# Tensorflow: Use softmax in training ,got result W,b value always as zero?

Tags: csv, tensorflow

I tried to write a tensorflow code to train samples for the first time, but I seems the weight factor W and b are always zero after every step of training.

The training data are very simple, that are 10000 samples (x,y) when 00.3, y=1. I imported these data from a csv file.
Traing data sotred in csv file shown as follows(There are 10000 data in total):

```
    0.487801884,1;
    0.457740109,1;
    0.092949029,-1;
    0.704023173,1;
    0.07851864,-1;
```

But when I run this code and print W and b in each step, I found W, b is always zero, seems like they are not been trained. Training result:

```
    W= [[ 0.  0.]]
    b= [ 0.  0.]
    Epoch: 0000000001 cost= 0.821999985 W= [[ 0.  0.]] b= [ 0.  0.]
    Optimization Finished!
    Accuracy: 1.0
```

I'm confused, could anyone help me to find what the problem is?Thank you very much!
Code is attched here:

```
#coding=utf-8
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import os
import csv
#training data sotred in csv file
filename=open('D:\Program Files (x86)\logistic\sample.csv','r')
reader=csv.reader(filename)

t_X,t_Y=[],[]

for i in reader:
    t_X.append(i[0])
    t_Y.append(i[1])

t_X=numpy.asarray(t_X)
t_Y=numpy.asarray(t_Y)
t_XT=numpy.transpose([t_X])
t_YT=numpy.transpose([t_Y])

#Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1
batch_size=50
display_step = 1

#Input
n_samples = t_X.shape[0]

#print "n_samples:",n_samples
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

#Weight
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

#model
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-pred))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost=0
        total_batch=int(n_samples/batch_size)

        i=0
        #read training data and transfer it into (m,n)
        for anc in range(total_batch):
            m=numpy.asarray([t_X[i],t_X[i+1],t_X[i+2],t_X[i+3],t_X[i+4]])
            n=numpy.asarray([t_Y[i],t_Y[i+1],t_Y[i+2],t_Y[i+3],t_Y[i+4]])
            m=numpy.transpose([m])
            n=numpy.transpose([n])

            _,c=sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={x: m, y: n})

            i=i+batch_size
            avg_cost += c/total_batch

        if (epoch+1)%display_step==0:           
            print ("Epoch:",'%010d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost),"W=",sess.run(W),"b=",sess.run(b))

    print ("Optimization Finished!")

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: t_XT, y: t_YT})
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Jep, you could expect this problem with this weight initialisation:

```
#Weight
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 2]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
```

Your weights should be initialised randomly ;)

Comment: Thank you! I replaced these two statements with the follows:W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 2],dtype=tf.float32))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2],dtype=tf.float32)), and it seems to work normally now:)

Comment: Perfect! It is a common mistake to make ;)

Comment: If you want to read more about this lookup "neural network symmetry breaking"